# I could not find the way to build a single query for getting the count of occurrences of distinct values

Tags: count, distinct, influxdb

Thank you in advance.

I just need to get a distinct count of these rows.

```
1539946464002000000 /vcg/_definst_/assets2/2018/07/20/178BFA56-1923-4E27-9F29-3B4DAACABA45/dash.smil/chunk_ctvideo_ridp0va0br3278733_cn192_mpd.m4s
1539946464003000000 /vsg/_definst_/assets2/2018/10/17/85080696-4B3A-4852-B572-B8787918AB45/hls.smil/playlist.m3u8
1539946464004000000 /vcg/_definst_/assets8/2018/03/20/CBA7ED48-5E57-439F-9646-91D8A8009C81/hls.smil/media_b128000_ao_sles_t64U3BhbmlzaA==_260.ts
1539946464005000000 /vsg/_definst_/assets17/2018/10/12/832977ED-AFA4-43AC-B7E9-FFD1CF6F9A45/es.smil/media_b2814000_209.ts
1539946464006000000 /vsg/_definst_/assets5/2017/12/26/D4C053D7-FD4E-4360-B49B-C16F98734F78/eshls.smil/media_b648000_184.ts
1539946464007000000 /vsg/_definst_/assets17/2018/08/10/615EB20B-8C88-4884-99DA-D3DD1084A4A9/es.smil/chunk_ctvideo_ridp0va0br820308_cn342_mpd.m4s
1539946464008000000 /vcg/_definst_/assets1/2018/05/21/FEA21F7A-D0F1-4EDC-89CC-6CDB889913C8/hls.smil/media_b2857000_vo_220.ts
1539946465000000000 /vcg/_definst_/smil:assets15/2018/10/12/DE919355-B070-43C7-BAF6-756E8419F64F/es.smil/media_b1348000_728.ts
1539946465001000000 /vsg/_definst_/assets3/2018/10/18/FFC31EF6-5856-45E5-834D-CCEE5AF0859A/es.smil/chunklist_b980000.m3u8
1539946465002000000 /vcg/_definst_/assets1/2018/05/21/FEA21F7A-D0F1-4EDC-89CC-6CDB889913C8/hls.smil/media_b2857000_vo_222.ts
1539946465003000000 /vsg/_definst_/assets3/2018/10/18/FFC31EF6-5856-45E5-834D-CCEE5AF0859A/es.smil/chunklist_b2050000.m3u8
1539946465004000000 /vsg/_definst_/assets15/2018/10/15/3597C92F-6761-43D6-9477-54DBB0EDB5B3/es.smil/media_b980000_492.ts
1539946465005000000 /vsg/_definst_/assets2/2018/10/17/85080696-4B3A-4852-B572-B8787918AB45/hls.smil/chunklist_b4821000_vo.m3u8
1539946465006000000 /vcg/_definst_/assets3/2018/01/03/FCF70321-9EAC-4FC0-B53C-B90C59446A2B/es.smil/playlist.m3u8
1539946466000000000 /vsg/_definst_/assets6/2015/03/18/9F9569CF-5222-4A51-94F4-AF0F0B1B6ED7/eshls.smil/media_b948000_153.ts
1539946466001000000 /vsg/_definst_/assets6/2018/10/11/91687B02-E10A-40CE-95CE-DEC496BFDFA7/hls.smil/chunklist_b128000_ao_sles_t64U3BhbmlzaA==.m3u8
1539946466002000000 /
1539946466003000000 /vsg/_definst_/assets17/2018/10/04/8D3F6D09-2A17-40B2-82F1-80A18385DEBE/hls.smil/chunklist_b4645000_vo.m3u8
1539946466004000000 /vcg/_definst_/assets6/2014/12/09/5F9923EB-1072-491B-A9DC-3EC2426C1632/hls.smil/media_b128000_ao_sles_t64U3BhbmlzaA==_117.ts
1539946466005000000 /vsg/_definst_/assets3/2018/10/18/B0BF19EA-D2F1-4C2B-B763-F74B27C99C66/es.smil/chunk_ctvideo_ridp0va0br821229_cn348_mpd.m4s
1539946466006000000 /
1539946466007000000 /vsg/_definst_/assets2/2018/10/17/85080696-4B3A-4852-B572-B8787918AB45/hls.smil/playlist.m3u8
1539946467000000000 /vcg/_definst_/assets6/2018/05/03/5822D814-F07C-4869-A531-AE87D29D2EAA/dash.smil/chunk_ctaudio_ridp0aa0br128000_cn148_mpd.m4s
1539946467001000000 /vsg/_definst_/assets2/2018/10/17/85080696-4B3A-4852-B572-B8787918AB45/hls.smil/chunklist_b3214000_vo.m3u8
1539946467002000000 /vcg/_definst_/assets12/2016/06/03/E52B7D3F-14F1-41DC-B04C-5A1178942651/hls.smil/media_b128000_ao_slen_t64RW5nbGlzaA==_22.ts
1539946468000000000 /vcg/_definst_/assets8/2018/09/04/517B3BE5-EA61-4F9D-86B2-0C1B705528B7/hls.smil/media_b5605000_vo_95.ts
1539946468001000000 /vcg/_definst_/smil:assets11/2018/10/06/C2C8ABE8-BBBB-41EA-927B-8212B26CC648/es.smil/media_b2225000_68.ts
1539946468002000000 /vcg/_definst_/assets5/2015/09/24/9D8EAE52-5502-4E92-B528-67A929726D6B/hls.smil/media_b5506000_vo_47.ts
1539946468003000000 /vcg/_definst_/assets17/2017/03/02/DE2FF16C-F1FB-433F-9EDE-C7C6F5A6D20A/es.smil/playlist.m3u8
1539946468004000000 /vsg/_definst_/assets6/2018/10/11/91687B02-E10A-40CE-95CE-DEC496BFDFA7/hls.smil/chunklist_b850000_vo.m3u8
1539946469000000000 /vsg/_definst_/assets8/2014/12/16/9BA3C6D1-0D93-423D-A5BA-9B94BAA147D4/eshls.smil/media_b1973000_351.ts
1539946469001000000 /vcg/_definst_/assets16/2017/02/15/73D35D9F-42A7-49EB-BAD6-A991E6279A79/es.smil/playlist.m3u8
1539946469002000000 /vcg/_definst_/assets3/2018/05/07/7E953A2A-B85A-431A-B0F3-3696732743D8/hls.smil/media_b1556000_vo_150.ts
1539946469003000000 /vcg/_definst_/assets16/2018/07/19/C44A6921-ADC9-4CF6-9582-0E5EF889FE7C/hls.smil/media_b600000_vo_77.ts
1539946469004000000 /vsg/_definst_/assets13/2016/10/02/74EFD7EA-F234-4C27-AFDF-64E632853073/es.smil/media_b1348000_5.ts
1539946469005000000 /vsg/_definst_/assets11/2015/12/21/CE981D0A-89CB-4AEC-A84D-6E69C51C30B2/es.smil/media_b2044000_355.ts
1539946469006000000 /vsg/_definst_/assets11/2018/10/15/76CD14E4-468A-4338-8CF1-76000D04ED9D/hls.smil/playlist.m3u8
1539946469007000000 /vcg/_definst_/assets14/2016/11/24/B1477367-356E-45F2-82A3-7596E2A360A2/eshls.smil/media_b1973000_287.ts
1539946469008000000 /vsg/_definst_/assets2/2018/09/17/DBCD85B7-CB35-4BFB-B21D-F8DB344746F5/dash.smil/chunk_ctvideo_ridp0va0br2793790_cn9_mpd.m4s
1539946469009000000 /vsg/_definst_/assets11/2018/10/15/76CD14E4-468A-4338-8CF1-76000D04ED9D/hls.smil/chunklist_b2241000_vo.m3u8
```

and that's impossible... In Oracle, it is so simple that this:

```
select distinct value, count(*) from table1 group by value
```

Any help would be so appreciated

Regards.

Comment: i did some Google and Stackoverflow search and i could find something helpfull, im sure and not looking properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT( <field_key> ))
```

https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.6/query_language/functions/#distinct